# Opening visual studio solution from a linux drive

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10-desktop

I just upgraded from Win7 to Win10 and I noticed the following change, that I don't explain for now.

I used to checkout my source code on in a mounted linux drive (\myremote\myaccount\ as X:)

before I was able to open visual studio 2008 solution (.sln file) and build but since the upgrade to Win10, devenv fails when I double click on a sln, saying that:

```
The following files were specified on the command line:
    X:\blahblah\myproject\myproject.sln
These files could not be found and will not be loaded
```

but I can open and save that sln file using a text editor.
Note that my `devenv` run as Administrator.

Any idea ?

Comment: Maybe something is changed with the permissions? Can you open the drive and the folder from your PC? Do you have write permissions?

Comment: Yes I can navigate into that folder with Visual Code or NotePad++, open a file, made a change and save it. I only have problem with Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you have a solution?  I am running in to the same scenario.  I suspect the problem is that c1xx (my project is C++) is attempting to request the files using backslashes as directory separators.

Comment: Hi @LMC, no solution for the moment, I'm still investigating as I don't have a clear view... I agree that / vs. \ may be a problem, but it's also possible that file access and permission are managed differently on win10 between the system itself and some old win32 app like Visual Studio